# Data Frame that keeps track of particular events in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have the following table:

```
Name        Date       Score
John      11-01-02      40
John      11-01-03      47
John      11-01-04      41
John      11-01-05      35
John      11-01-06      52
John      11-01-07      47
John      11-01-08      45
John      11-01-09      43
John      11-01-10      40
Adam      11-01-02      41
Adam      11-01-03      41
Adam      11-01-04      49
Adam      11-01-05      40
Adam      11-01-06      40
```

I just wanna keep track of the following events: for each student, keep track of when and how many times a student had either 1) a score increase of 5 or more, followed by a score decrease of 5 or more   or   2) a score decrease of 5 or more, followed by a score increase of 5 or more.

I made the following table to help the above task: a table of differences between scores for each student.

```
Name        Date      Difference
John      11-01-03       7
John      11-01-04      -6
John      11-01-05      -6
John      11-01-06      17
John      11-01-07      -5
John      11-01-08      -2
John      11-01-09      -2
John      11-01-10      -3
Adam      11-01-04       8
Adam      11-01-05      -9
Adam      11-01-06       0
```

For instance, on 11-01-03, John's score went up to 47 from 40 on 11-01-02, so there's a difference of 47-40=7.

I want the following table as output:

One that keeps track of names, dates for events

```
Name        Dates for Events
John            11-01-03      
John            11-01-05
John            11-01-06
Adam            11-01-04
```

On 11-01-03, John experienced a score change of 7, followed by -6, so John experienced the event that I described. Other dates were included for same reason.

Is there an easy way of doing so in R? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `John      11-01-05` should be in and `John            11-01-07` should not (two successive decrease)

Comment: @denis   yeah. i edited. thx

Comment: and `John            11-01-03` should be in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` could be as:

```
data %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(diff = lead(Score) - Score,
         score_increase_5 = ifelse(diff >= 5, TRUE, FALSE),
         score_decrease_5 = ifelse(diff <= -5, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(diff)) %>%
  mutate(event = ((score_decrease_5 & lag(score_increase_5)) |
  (score_increase_5 & lag(score_decrease_5)))) %>%
  filter(event) %>%
  select(Name, Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to create two column with the difference with the previous line, and the difference with the following line. You then select the sub-data.frame with a condition.

Here is the solution with data.table

```
library(data.table)
plouf <- read.table(text = "
Name        Date       Score
John      11-01-02      40
John      11-01-03      47
John      11-01-04      41
John      11-01-05      35
John      11-01-06      52
John      11-01-07      47
John      11-01-08      45
John      11-01-09      43
John      11-01-10      40
Adam      11-01-02      41
Adam      11-01-03      41
Adam      11-01-04      49
Adam      11-01-05      40
Adam      11-01-06      40",header = T)
plouf <- setDT(plouf)
plouf[,Score:= as.numeric(Score)]
plouf[,diffprev := c(NA,diff(Score)), by = Name]
plouf[,difffol :=c(Score[2:.N]-Score[1:(.N-1)],NA),by = Name]
```

and you do the selection

```
plouf[(diffprev >= 5 & difffol <= -5) |(diffprev <= -5 & difffol >= 5),.(Name,Date)]
```

gives

```
> plouf[(diffprev >= 5 & difffol <= -5) |(diffprev <= -5 & difffol >= 5)]
   Name     Date Score diffprev difffol
1: John 11-01-03    47        7      -6
2: John 11-01-05    35       -6      17
3: John 11-01-06    52       17      -5
4: Adam 11-01-04    49        8      -9
```